# class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered

Tags: uitableview, pagination, avplayeritem

I'm getting the following error, but the strange thing is that it only happens when I do a scroll on my tableview using the pagination, loading a second set of posts, and than I try to move out to new view controller,
if I load only the first page of posts, and move out to another view controller, there is no crash:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'An instance 0x170212330 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key 
value observers were still registered with it. 
Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x174820360> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x174244290: Observer: 0x101c76c00, Key path: 
playbackBufferEmpty, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, 
Property: 0x174243ea0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x1754583c0: Observer: 0x101c76c00, Key path: 
playbackLikelyToKeepUp, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, 
Property: 0x174243f60>
```

I have a player on my cell, here is my code for view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewSelected cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *identifier = @"postCell";
    PostCell* updateCell = [tableViewSelected dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"ADD VIDEO PLAYER and PLAY VIDEO");



                NSString* videoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",UrlBase,PostVideos,post.video];
                NSString* expandedPath = [videoString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                 NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:expandedPath];
                NSLog(@"URL : %@",videoURL);


                updateCell.videoItem  = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];

                [updateCell.videoItem addObserver:updateCell forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
                [updateCell.videoItem addObserver:updateCell forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

                updateCell.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:updateCell.videoItem];
                updateCell.avLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:updateCell.videoPlayer];
                updateCell.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:updateCell selector:@selector(itemDidBufferPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification object:nil];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:updateCell selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[updateCell.videoPlayer currentItem]];


                updateCell.avLayer.frame = updateCell.picture.bounds;
                [updateCell.videoView.layer addSublayer:updateCell.avLayer];

                [updateCell.avLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
                if(indexPath.row==0){
                    [updateCell.videoPlayer play];
                }
            });
        });
        return updateCell;

}
```

And the only difference I can see from adding a second page is:

When doing regular table view load I do:

```
  [_tableView reloadData];
```

When loading a second page on the same table view I do:

```
 [_tableView beginUpdates];
 [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[[GlobalSingleton sharedInstance] indexPathsToInsert]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
 [_tableView endUpdates];
```

Than on my Cell I do:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse{
    [self removePlayer];

}

- (void) dealloc {
[self removePlayer];
}

-(void)removePlayer{
    @try{

    [self.videoItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty"];
    [self.videoItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"];




    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];

        NSLog(@"remove Observer!");
    // [avLayer.player pause];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"finally");
        [self.avLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        self.playIV.hidden = YES;
        self.videoActivity.hidden = YES;
        self.videoView.hidden = YES;
        self.videoItem = nil;
        self.avLayer = nil;
        self.videoPlayer = nil;
    }

}
```

Is it possible that insertRowsAtIndexPaths is causing the cells to never be dealloc? I can't find how its possible to have the observers registered.

Comment: My solution was to remove the 2 first observers:
      [updateCell.videoItem addObserver:updateCell forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];[updateCell.videoItem addObserver:updateCell forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

Comment: Also I figured out prepareForReuse does not seem work well with insertRowsAtIndexPaths, but if I remove the observers on cellForRowAtIndexPath before creating the new videoItem, it also works.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow when using the insertRowsAtIndexPaths, the prepareForReuse is not been called, so I resolved it by unregistering the observers on the cellForRowAtIndexPath before adding a new videoItem to the Cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewSelected cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *identifier = @"postCell";
PostCell* updateCell = [tableViewSelected dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSString* videoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",UrlBase,PostVideos,post.video];
            NSString* expandedPath = [videoString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:expandedPath];

            /** SOLUTION STARTS HERE **/
            @try{
                  [self.videoItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty"];
                  [self.videoItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"];
                  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification object:nil];
                  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];

           }
           @catch (NSException * e) {
               NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
           }
           @finally {
               NSLog(@"finally");
           }
           /** SOLUTION ENDS HERE **/

            updateCell.videoItem  = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];
            [updateCell.videoItem addObserver:updateCell forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
            [updateCell.videoItem addObserver:updateCell forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

            updateCell.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:updateCell.videoItem];
            updateCell.avLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:updateCell.videoPlayer];
            updateCell.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:updateCell selector:@selector(itemDidBufferPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification object:nil];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:updateCell selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[updateCell.videoPlayer currentItem]];


            updateCell.avLayer.frame = updateCell.picture.bounds;
            [updateCell.videoView.layer addSublayer:updateCell.avLayer];

            [updateCell.avLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
            if(indexPath.row==0){
                [updateCell.videoPlayer play];
            }
        });
    });
    return updateCell;

}
```